# Class MailApp modify the from name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(senderemail, replytoemail, subject, body)
```

to send emails from a non gmail account via a google spreadsheet script and it is working as intended. Because it's not a gmail account I can't modify the name of the account and the "from" sender name is just the part of the address before the "@" which happens to be "info". I want to modify that name to be the company name. I tried using:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(senderemail, replytoemail, subject, body, {name:'Company Name'})
```

as detailed in this [Google app script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29) but this is not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the method `sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)` use `replyTo` as an email address not a name.
you should use:
`sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`with `option`an object like this:
`{name:"some name"}`
that will give you:
`sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {name:"some name"})`
if you want to use `replytoemail`then the replyToEmail address need to be one alias of your account, check the doc [Add or remove an email alias](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?hl=en)

Comment: You can pass the `replyTo` as an Advanced parameter in the `options` Object like this:  `MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {name:"some name", replyTo: 'replyto@mydomain.com'})`

Comment: I don't have a google for work account but the first line of code in my question above is working and providing a reply to email address.   `MailApp.sendEmail(senderemail, replytoemail, subject, body)`

Comment: method `sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)` don't take a fifth argument you need to use `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`and put in the `options` object the name and the replyto : `{name:"lalala", replyTo:"some@email.ext"}`

Comment: Thank you very much